# improper integral converge and diverge

Tags: analysis

this problem is

$ f(x) = (x^2sin(1/x^2))' = 2xsin(1/x^2)-\frac{2}{x}cos(1/x^2) $

show that the improper Riemann integral of f converges on (0,1]

but that the improper integral of |f| diverges on (0,1].

I know f converges on (0,1]. but I don't know how to prove that |f| diverges on (0,1]

I try to prove by comparison test , but it is really comlicated

Answer (score 1):

First notice that:
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\sin(1)-\lim_{x\to 0}x^2\sin(\tfrac{1}{x^2})=1.
$$
On the other hand, $$
\int_0^1\left\vert 2x\sin(\tfrac{1}{x^2})-\tfrac{2}{x}\cos(\tfrac{1}{x^2})\right\vert dx>2\int_0^1\left\vert\tfrac{1}{x}\cos(\tfrac{1}{x^2})\right\vert dx-2\int_0^1 xdx=+\infty,
$$
where it's easy to see that the first integral diverges by doing the change of variables $u=\tfrac{1}{x}$. Also notice that clearly the second integral in the right-hand side is finite, so they cannot cancel.

Edit: Just to be more specific, notice that after this change of variables the first integral becomes $$
\int_1^\infty \left\vert\tfrac{1}{x}\cos(x^2)\right\vert dx,
$$
which, as it's said in the comments, it is easy to bound.

Comment: (*) is not correct: With $u = 1/x$ you have $\int_0^1 \frac{|\cos(1/x^2)|}{x} \, dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{|\cos(u^2)}{u}\, du$. Hence, your argument for divergence based on the limit comparison is invalid.  Nevertheless this first integral is divergent and this can be shown in other ways found by searching on this site.

Comment: (+1) for the correct approach otherwise.

Comment: Oh, you are totally right, my bad!

Comment: ㄴ Oct   where is the site?